# AVD Screen orientation not changing with CTRL+F11 or CTRL+F12

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation, android-virtual-device

I run my app in the AVD emulator using eclipse but I'm unable to change the screen orientation in the AVD (Android 2.0 platform on the emulator).

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on the keyboard, nothing happens. No messages are generated in the adb debuglog/logcat either when I press either hotkey.

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html these are the correct hotkeys to switch the emulator's screen orientation.

I tried it with my app, and with the messaging app. The hotkey has no affect in any case.

I'm running Fedora 12, Gnome. I checked my Keyboard Shortcuts in the System -> Preferences menu, nothing's attached to either hotkey.

Same problem, 3 different PCs (all running Fedora Gnome).

Comment: Use Right Ctrl, dont use left Ctrl.

Comment: Lleft control don't even work. What do you mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can also use keypad <kbd>7</kbd> and keypad <kbd>9</kbd>, did you try them?

Comment: Just tried - no affect and the numbers come through to the app, so in the messaging app, I see the 7 and 9 characters in the editText box.

Comment: OK I just re-installed Eclipse and the SDK on a desktop. Its also running Fedora+Gnome. Although the function keys don't work, the keypad 7 & 9 do work (with numlock off). Accepting this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also just discovered on my laptop that I can change orientation using FUNCTION+7 and FUNCTION+9

Comment: "Just tried - no affect" you should have turned num lock keys **OFF**. It works for me in xfce session

Comment: although the AVD does change orientation, it has no effect on the apps that are running on the AVD. Is this what others are seeing or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using [android:screenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) to lock it into one or the other?

Comment: Same problem with the messaging app, as I specified in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a feature, such as an accessibility one that allows the mouse pointer to be moved with the numpad keys, turned on. I somehow accidently enabled this in Ubuntu, and it was hard to tell what was going on, because I didn't hold the keys down long enough for the pointer didn't move much. Going to Keyboard Preferences->Mouse Keys and unchecking "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad" fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd> .Worked with Xfce4,on Archlinux.